# How to create a list to hold images inside a webix form

Tags: webix

I have a webix form like below:

```
var myform = {
    id: "formID",
    view : "form",
    scroll: false,
    elements : datasheet,
    rules  : {
        "name":webix.rules.isNotEmpty
    }
};

var datasheet = [ 
    {view:"text", label:'Name', name:"fname", value: "Put your name"},
    {view: "checkbox", id:"field_a", label:"Second age",  value:1},
    {view: "template", template: "Header Template", type: "header"},
    {view: "template", template:"<div id= 'mydiv'><ul><li>1st item</li><li>2nd item</li></ul></div>"}
   ]
```

In similar fashion as above, I want to have a list (< ul> < /ul> or < li> < /li>, may be inside a div) to hold some image items. How can I define that inside the datasheet variable above so that I can manage that list later by populating or removing items.

Thanks.

Comment: I have added the part of the code which will show a list inside a div. However, it is  a static list. I want a dynamic list instead to which later on I can add items (images especially) from a list of items (array) fetched from an AJAX call (may be). Any help on how can it be managed dynamically would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place a webix list widget inside of the form. You can use all lists API against it ( load, add, delete, update, etc. )

```
var datasheet = [ 
    {view:"text", label:'Name', name:"fname", value: "Put your name"},
    {view: "checkbox", id:"field_a", label:"Second age",  value:1},
    {view: "template", template: "Header Template", type: "header"},
    { view:"list", id:"form_list" }
];
```

https://webix.com/snippet/5ac32116

Comment: Thanks for the help.